# Problem with "Openzeppelin ERC20Votes delegate function"

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts, dao

I hope you're doing great. I have been tinkering with `ERC20Votes` and creating a DAO for my `Vendor` contract. The issue I'm facing is that whenever I try to delegate my `GovernanceToken` contract to the deployer and check the `numCheckpoints` function it shows `Checkpoint: 0`.

If I'm correct, upon successful delegation to the deployer or any address the checkpoint should be at 1.

Here are my `VendorGovernanceToken.sol` contract and my `deploy-governance-token.js` script.

1. VendorGovernanceToken.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Votes.sol";

contract VendorGovernanceToken is ERC20, ERC20Permit, ERC20Votes {
    constructor() ERC20("GovernanceToken", "GNT") ERC20Permit("GovernanceToken") {}

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _update(address from, address to, uint256 value) internal override(ERC20, ERC20Votes) {
        super._update(from, to, value);
    }

    function nonces(address owner) public view override(ERC20Permit, Nonces) returns (uint256) {
        return super.nonces(owner);
    }
}
```

2. deploy-governance-token.js

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { verify } = require("../utils/verification");
const {networkConfig, developmentChains} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");



module.exports = async function({getNamedAccounts, deployments}) {
    const {deploy, log} = deployments;
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts();

    log("------------------------------------------------------------");
    log("Deploying Governance Token...");

    const governanceToken = await deploy("VendorGovernanceToken", {
        from: deployer,
        log: true,
        args: [],
        waitConfirmations: 1
    });

    log(`Governance Token deployed at ${governanceToken.address}`);

    if(!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying contract please wait...");
        await verify(governanceToken, []);
    }

    log(`Delegating to ${deployer}`);

    const vendorGovernanceTokenContract = await ethers.getContractAt("VendorGovernanceToken", governanceToken.address);

    const tx = await vendorGovernanceTokenContract.delegate(deployer);
    await tx.wait(1);

    console.log(`Checkpoints: ${ await vendorGovernanceTokenContract.numCheckpoints(deployer)}`);

    log("Successfully Delegated");
    log("------------------------------------------------------------");
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "GTN", "Governance"];
```

3. Terminal Output

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Deploying Governance Token...
deploying "VendorGovernanceToken" (tx: 0x7e787d1f4ba66d80c124b4b9dd8e9f59d2a18254b2ace53adff58deb76ff7eae)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 3238170 gas
Governance Token deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
Delegating to 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
Checkpoints: 0
Successfully Delegated
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The contract won't increase the checkpoint if you have 0 tokens. You can test it by minting some tokens to the deployer in the constructor:

```
    constructor() ERC20("GovernanceToken", "GNT") ERC20Permit("GovernanceToken") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }
```